# How to add html class to asp.net mvc 4 html helpers?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Trying to add a bootstrap class to an input generated by EditorFor but not working...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

without helper working fine:

```
<input class ="form-control" name="Name" type="Text" value="@Model.Nome" />
```

Comment: Your way is correct @Rieth. it should work. Use F12 i.e. developer tools in the browser and inspect what is the html getting generated for the element and the style/class being applied to the element. You can get a clue from there.

Comment: You cannot add attributes to `EditorFor()` in MVC-4. The feature was not added until MVC-5.1. You need to use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MVC are you using?

Support for htmlAttributes was added to MVC 5.1. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes

Answer (score 0):

You might need to assign the class inside the editor template and in the custom template as shown below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Summary)

<div>
    @Html.TextBoxForModel(x => x.Summary, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

For more information you might have  a look at [Html.EditorFor and htmlAttributes](http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/). Hope this helps...

Comment: @Rieth The answer was updated.